# "Are you sure to leave this page" javascript function inside <img>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good Day,

Recently, am working on page where a certain `button` (an image icon resembles a button for exiting the page) is present at the top right most of its corner.
`<img src="img/logout.png">` Once the user clicked this said `button/icon` a pop-up message will show on screen prompting "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Yes | No " similar with stackoverflow. If the user click yes, then he/she will be directed to another page; if no, then he/she will be brought back to current page where he/she's into. But i dunno if that would work on an `<img>` tag. Anyhow, Iv'e tried to run this ff. code:

index.php

```
var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
if(answer){

window.location =("dashboard.php");
}
else{
window.location =("index.php");
}
```

Then I placed the function call inside the `<img>` tag that looks like this: `<img src="img/logout.png" onMouseUp="answer()">`

**Result:**
When I tried to run it, the pop-up message was keeping on display regardless if I presses either yes or no, it's still on the screen.

Think I might've missed something... anyone who knows what to do with it?

Comment: Why onmouseup? instead of that you should use onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of all that you can Just add this in your head section of page

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return " are you sure! you want to leave this page"; }
```